# How can you count the characters in a string with for loop

Tags: python, string, loops, for-loop, character

I want to create a little code to count the numbers and letters in a string. I have a mistake somewhere because the code returns only the last character of the string. This is what I get when I run the code:

```
Enter something world1
Letters: 1
Numbers: 1
```

For example what I want as an answer here is Letters: 5, Numbers: 1.

Here's my code

```
string = input("Enter something ")
numbers=0
letters=0
for x in string:
    if x.isnumeric():
        pass
    elif x.isalpha():
        pass
    else:
        letters = letters + 1
print("Letters: " + x[letters])
print("Numbers: " + x[numbers])
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Seems like you should be adding to your counts in your `if` and `elif` instead of just `pass`ing, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be incrementing `numbers` or `letters` when `x.isnumeric()` or `x.isalpha()` respectively. And you should be printing out `numbers` and `letters` instead of `x[letters]`, which will more than likely throw an Exception since `x` is a string of length 1 and `letters` may very well be greater than 0.

```py
string = input("Enter something ")
numbers = 0
letters = 0
for x in string:
    if x.isnumeric():
        numbers += 1
    elif x.isalpha():
        letters += 1

print('String:', string)
print("Letters:",  letters)
print("Numbers:", numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not really count the number of letters and numbers in a string.

Notice the first two conditions inside the for loop.

```
if x.isnumeric():
    pass
elif x.isalpha():
    pass
```

If the character (which is x) is either a number or a letter, it just skips or pass and do nothing.

Moreover, the else won't be executed unless there are symbols.
Therefore the value of **letters** and **numbers** variable will be 0 after the for loop ends.

Another problem, you are using the variable x which represents the last character of the string (because of the last iteration). Then, you used the **letters** and **numbers** variable as index which is 0. That is why, it outputs the last character.

**x[letters]** --> **x[0]** --> **1**

```
print("Letters: " + x[letters])
print("Numbers: " + x[numbers])
```

**TO SOLVE**

- Increment **numbers** and **letters** variable by 1 instead of using the pass keyword.
- Use the variables (numbers and letters) itself, no need to use x with indexing.

  ```
  string = input("Enter something ")
  numbers=0
  letters=0
  for x in string:
      if x.isnumeric():
          numbers += 1
      elif x.isalpha():
          letters += 1
  print("Letters: " + str(letters))
  print("Numbers: " + str(numbers))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = input("Enter something ")
numbers=0
letters=0
for x in string:
    if x.isnumeric():
        numbers = numbers + 1
    elif x.isalpha():
        letters = letters + 1

        
print(f"Letters: {letters}")
print(f"Numbers: {numbers}")
```

Answer (score 0):

*Hi , I have worked on your code and corrected it.
Can you try the below code .*

```
string = input("Enter something ")
numbers=0
letters=0
for x in string:
    if x.isnumeric():
     pass
      numbers=numbers+1
     elif x.isalpha():
       pass
      letters=letters+1
     else:
      letters=letters+1
print("Letters: {0}".format(letters ))
print("Numbers: {0}".format(numbers ))
```